# Unable to dismiss $modalInstance angular bootstrap $modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I've opened a modal using $modal.open and taking the return value which is a modal instance to a variable. When I try to close the $modal using that modal instance's either dismiss() or close() methods it is not closing. When I tried to check the $$state.value for the modal instance that I've taken in to variable I don't see it present and $$state.state is also coming as 0. I couldn't understand why is it happening so, could this be reason why I'm not able to close the modal. I could clearly see the modal is opened. Does anyone know why is it so? Has anyone faced the similar issue?

```
    var modalOpened = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: modalOptions.template,
                        controller: modalOptions.cntrlr,
                        windowClass: modalOptions.winClass,
                        backdrop: modalOptions.backdrop,
                        resolve: {
                            modalParams: function () {
                                return params;
                            }
                        }
                    });

   modalOpened.dismiss('cancel');
```

Comment: It works, just don't try to close it before it's opened. Try `setTimeout(function() { modalOpened.dismiss('cancel'); }, 50);` for example.